# Why does double free or corruption error not happen at run time for boost ptr_container?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I was testing out boost ptr_containers and wrote a small program as below:

```
class Test {
    public:
        ~Test() {
            cout << "Test Destructor called" << endl;
         }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    boost::ptr_map<int, Test> TestContainer;
    boost::ptr_vector<Test> TestVector;
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        Test* ptr = new Test();
        TestContainer.insert(i, ptr);
        TestVector.push_back(ptr);
    }

}
```

Once I execute the program, "Test Destructor called" is printed four time and program completes successfully. I was expecting the printing will happen 2 times and then "doube free..." error message would be thrown. Why does it not happen in the above case, but it happens with a raw pointer (Test*)?

Comment: If you purposefully write programs that invoke undefined behavior, then anything can be expected including "working", crashing, etc.

Comment: A double free error is undefined behavior, and undefined behavior does not mean "crash" ( http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html ), although a crash is a valid result.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding of UB.  Undefined Behavior can mean *Unpredictable Behavior*.  That's why you're having trouble predicting the behavior.

Comment: How do I make it a predictable behavior or how to catch such situations in my code? It is likely someone could inser the same pointer into two different containers.

Comment: Stop using raw pointers to hold resources?  `std::unique_ptr` represents ownership and the pointer at the same time.  Don't transfer ownership via `.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr_map` and `ptr_vector` own their elements.

The program is incorrect. Inserting the same elements in two containers at once leads to double deletion.

The behaviour of delete on an already-deleted pointer is undefined. Anything can happen. See **[Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**

Use a tool like valgrind to catch this.

---

In case you did want to know, easiest way to fix this sample is by using non-owning pointers for one of the containers. Be sure to manage relative lifetimes of the elements:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Test {
    public:
        ~Test() {
            std::cout << "Test Destructor called" << std::endl;
         }
};

int main() {

    boost::ptr_vector<Test> TestVector;
    {
        std::map<int, Test*> TestContainer;

        for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
            Test* ptr = new Test();
            TestContainer.emplace(i, ptr);
            TestVector.push_back(ptr);
        }
    }

}
```